# ¿Como puedo hacer esta consulta en queryBuilder eloquen de laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Tengo esta consulta en sql

```
"select
        a.id,
        a.start as startDate,
        a.minute_duration_class,
        a.max_student,
        a.status,
        a.execution,
        a.id_type_class,
        ut.id as teacherId,
        c.name,
        p.name as programName,
        tc.name as typeClass
        from available a
        inner join users ut on a.id_user_teacher = ut.id
        inner join course c on c.id = a.id_course
        inner join program p on p.id = c.id_program
        inner join typeclass tc on tc.id = a.id_type_class
        inner join booking b on b.id_available = b.id
        where ut.identification = '71315231'
        and a.execution = 'pendiente' and a.start between '2020-10-13 00:00:00' and '2020-11-11 00:00:00'
        group by a.id,ut.id,c.name,p.name,tc.name
        having (select count(*) from booking bo inner join available a2 on bo.id_available = a2.id where bo.id_available = a.id) =
        (select count(*) from classattendance ca inner join booking bo2 on bo2.id = ca.id_booking inner join available a2 on a2.id = bo2.id_available where a2.id = a.id)
        order by a.id desc"
```

El resultado de esta consulta necesito ppaginarla en laravel, por ende me toca consultar con eloquent.
¿hay forma de transformar esta consulta con eloquent para luego paginar?.

Comment: Claro que hay una forma, pero qué has intentado hasta ahora?

Comment: Tranformarla si, tal vez lo que te va a llevar mas tiempo será la paginación, esta no trabaja del todo bien cuando la consulta incluye group by, lo dice la documentación de Laravel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Muchas gracias por tu respuesta Emmanuel, igual estuve mirando y encontre esto antes, aunque claramente me roja un valor similar a la página de la respuesta anterior.

```
        $availables = DB::table('available as a')
            ->join('users as ut','a.id_user_teacher','=','ut.id')
            ->join('course as c','c.id','=','a.id_course')
            ->join('program as p','p.id','=','c.id_program')
            ->join('typeclass as tc','a.id_type_class','=','tc.id')
            ->join('booking as b', 'b.id_available', 'a.id')
            ->select('a.id as id',
                'a.start as startDate',
                'a.minute_duration_class',
                'a.max_student',
                'a.status',
                'a.execution',
                'a.id_type_class',
                'ut.id as teacherId',
                'c.name',
                'p.name as programName',
                'tc.name as typeClass'
                )
            ->where('ut.id',$idTeacher)
            ->where('a.execution', 'pendiente')
            ->whereBetween('a.start',[Carbon::parse('2020-10-13'),Carbon::now()])
            ->groupBy('a.id', 'ut.id', 'c.name', 'p.name', 'tc.name')
            ->havingRaw("(select count(*) from booking bo inner join available a2 on bo.id_available = a2.id where bo.id_available = a.id) >
            (select count(*) from classattendance ca inner join booking bo2 on bo2.id = ca.id_booking inner join available a2 on a2.id = bo2.id_available where a2.id = a.id)")
            ->orderBy('a.id','desc')
            ->paginate(12);
```